# GTM History Change Listener Missing Pageviews in GA

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using the history fragment to capture the url after the hash for an angular-based site we've built.

Not all my pages are showing up under All Pages in Google Analytics - but DO show when i add page as a secondary dimension to events.

I think this is to do with using the history change trigger to send url fragment as a pageview, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

How do I make sure an exit page is captured, even though it isn't reloaded hence no new history fragment?

(register.creditunions.com = tracks fine, but when someone completes, it goes to /confirm, which they leave, and which is not tracking. I have the confirmed sign ups in my CMS, and they HAVE to go through to that page to get signed up, hence i know i'm not just asking about a page that isn't being seen.)

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics doesn't detect URL fragments as a part of page path out of the box. You need some tweaks to force tracking of anything after the hash. There is a lot of recipes all over the web. Try this one https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-url-fragments-as-pageviews/

Comment: Thanks! Thats the exact one I have implemented already! :) Simple but just this one issue is left. Per Simo, it seems like the PV isn't firing every time.